# Running multiple bash scripts using sbatch

Tags: linux, bash, slurm

I an using the cluster, and I have been running my bash scripts using

```
$sbatch file1.sh
$sbatch file2.sh
```

Is there a way that I can run all my bash scripts at once, maybe using a wildcard?

Comment: `for script in ./*; do sbatch "$script"; done`